# What does this sentence mean exactly?

Tags: meaning

**I edited the sentence so it gives better sense to you guys & thank you:**

These effects are rather as of the psychic forces of the body not being brought into cooperation with the physical forces, that have been first, primarily, a karmic influence. This means because of former activities, former relationships, brought about that, as to meet or to be met in self that which was condemned in another.

Was condemned in another - I can’t really understand this words combination in the sentence

Could you please translate for me the meaning of the whole sentence and especially the end? I am not a native speaker, thank you!!!!

Kristyna from the Czech Republic

Comment: I'm afraid I can't understand it, or even decipher a grammatical reading.

Comment: It means that your past actions and relationships forces you into the realisation of the discovery, in your own character, of that which you have judged to be bad in someone else.

Comment: **Translate** is an apt verb. But "that which was condemned in another" could refer to something about the speaker, which was disliked in somebody else.

Comment: It means that someone doesn't know how to write clear English.  Or is intentionally obfuscating.

Comment: It's quite possible that the author isn't a native speaker either. The sentence doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Don’t worry about understanding this sentence. It is poorly constructed and its meaning is not clear. Forget it.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much people for that effort to help me! I didn’t expect that...I edited the sentence - I add the. beginning so it. might help you to understand the meaning. Thank you so much, Kristýna